# Need help scaling and rotating an image in a viewport

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the code in this JSFidle - https://jsfiddle.net/pmi2018/smewua0k/211/

Javascript

```
$('#rotate').click(function(e) {
  updateImage(90, 0)
  console.log("rotation");
});

$('#zoom-in').click(function() {
  updateImage(0, 0.1);
  console.log("Zoomed in");
});

$('#zoom-out').click(function() {
  updateImage(0, -0.1);
  console.log("Zoomed out");
});

var zoomLevel = 1;
var rotation = 0;

var updateImage = function(angle, zoom) {
  zoomLevel += zoom;
  var img_scale = ' scale(' + zoomLevel + ') ';

  rotation += angle;
  if (rotation == 360) {
    rotation = 0;
  }
  var str_rotation = ' rotate(' + rotation + 'deg) ';
  console.log("rotation=" + str_rotation + " scale=" + img_scale);
  var img = document.getElementById('sam');
  img.style.transform = img_scale + str_rotation
  //if (angle == 0) {
  //   img.style.transformOrigin = '0 0';
  //   img.style.transform = img_scale;   
  // }
  // else {
  //   img.style.transformOrigin = 'center center';
  //   img.style.transform = str_rotation; 
  // }
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" id="zoom-in">zoom in</button> <button type="button" id="zoom-out">zoom out</button> 

<div id=imageblock>
  <img  id="sam" src="http://placekitten.com/g/250/250" />
</div>
<div>
  <a id="rotate" href="#">Rotate 90 degrees</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#imageblock {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}

#sam {
  transform-origin: center, center;
}
```

The problem is I need the have the origin be upper left corner when I scale the image to keep the scaled image in the box; but the origin has to be center, center when I rotate the image to keep the image in the box. However the CSS articles I have read say when rotating and scaling an image, they have to be done together.

I tried applying the rotation and scale separately so I could set the origin correctly (the commented out code), but only the first transform fires, and not the second.

How can I rotate and scale the image in the #imagebox?

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it "goes together" is because the transform property can only have one origin. So if you apply multiple transformations on a single object, they will all use the same origin.

An easy solution would be to put the image in a div. Then, use the zoom on the div, and the rotate on the image for exemple so that both can have different origins.

```js
$('#rotate').click(function(e) {
  updateImage(90, 0)
});

$('#zoom-in').click(function() {
  updateImage(0, 0.1);
});

$('#zoom-out').click(function() {
  updateImage(0, -0.1);
});

var zoomLevel = 1;
var rotation = 0;

var updateImage = function(angle, zoom) {
  zoomLevel += zoom;
  var img_scale = ' scale(' + zoomLevel + ') ';

  rotation += angle;
  if (rotation == 360) {
    rotation = 0;
  }
  var str_rotation = ' rotate(' + rotation + 'deg) ';

  // Here I modified the syntax just a bit, to use JQuery methods instead of pur Javascript. I hope you are ok with it
  // I modify the image rotate property, and then the div scale property
  $('#sam').css('transform',str_rotation)
  $('#zoom').css('transform', img_scale);
}
```

```css
#imageblock {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden; /* To hide the scrollbar when you zoom in */
}

#zoom {
  transform:scale(1);
  transform-origin:top left;
}

#sam {
  transform: rotate(0deg)
  transform-origin: center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" id="zoom-in">zoom in</button> <button type="button" id="zoom-out">zoom out</button> 

<div id=imageblock>
  <div id="zoom"> <!-- I added this div -->
    <img  id="sam" src="http://placekitten.com/g/250/250" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <a id="rotate" href="#">Rotate 90 degrees</a>
</div>
```

Also, please note that there is no coma in `transform-origin: center center;`.

Ask them if you have any questions. I hope it helped !